# Timeout in connection to a SQL Server instance in LAN

Tags: sql-server, timeout, sql-server-2008-r2

From one windows 7 machine I cannot connect anymore to any sql server instance that is in LAN and in same domain of this particular machine. I cannot connect from Management Studio, but also from any client server application.

I use sql serer autentication and this has always worked until a few days ago I installed some vpn software. Now I uninstalled it anyway the problem persisted.

I tried to do from the command prompt `ipconfig /fulshdns` (I did "Run as administrator") but it didn't help.

What can it be? Is there a place where I can manually check?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your TCP/IP stack got mangled. As an administrator, from the command line try:

```
    netsh int ip reset C:\log.log
```

Comment: I tried that but with no result. By the way I am able to browse from windows explorer a folder on that server. FOr example I can access \\SERVER01\SomeSHaredFolder, but I cannot log in to sql server on SERVER01\SQLEXPRESS. From all other machines in domain I can do both things succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your VPN software is blocking port 1433 which is used by SQL Server?